# Strange computer startup

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I have an HP G1 800 (i5 4670) tower system. It got it's capacitors burnt so I took it to a repair shop and replaced it's motherboard.

Now here is the main issue:

Whenever I turn the computer on after it is turned off, the red light blinks with beep, 5 beeps and red lights for five times. After that the fans start spinning very fast that you can hear them clearly.

Now if I turn it off immediately by pulling the power cable or by long pressing power button and turn it on it would do the same red light and beeps same as above would happen.

But if I let the fans spin, basically let fans keep spinning very fast for about 4 to 5 minutes and then turn it off and then turn on, The computer starts regularly just like any normal boot, no red light no beep and I can keep using it for as long as I want until it is turned off, I sometimes play games, do some processor heavy work, basically everything for whole day, nothing happens until I turn it off.

Once it is turned off, it will do the same issue again and I have to wait for 4 to 5 minutes before it could be booted normally.

So guys can you help me finding out what could be the issue?

The CPU and GPU temperatures are normal and do not go high.

Comment: You will need to count the specific number of flashes and beeps to find out what is wrong. 5 beeps indicates a serious error but the flashes give a more specific problem. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/715780/Hp-Eliteone-800-G1.html?page=199

Comment: Did it start doing this immediately after the motherboard replacement? If so, take it back to the shop.

Comment: @gronostaj yes it did, however when I took it to the shop back, it seemed to start normally when they checked, for me as well it sometimes start without any problems but that is rare

Comment: @Mokubai yes I checked, the thing is the red light just keep flashing without any delay until it is turned off so unable to count it correctly, that's why I just counted it with the beeps

Answer (score 0):

According to the page 31 on the [HP G1 800 User Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01516072) you have an issue with the RAM modules inside the computer. You should be able to clear this problem by re-seating each RAM stick carefully.

[image]

If you say you recently had the machine go to a computer repair shop, then they may have re-installed your RAM sticks incorrectly in the wrong slots, or worst case the motherboard is damaged.  Try re-seating the RAM modules first though, as we often find this to usually be the case.